# SpringBoot MVC - Post ThymeLeaf Object

Tags: spring-mvc, object, spring-boot, post, thymeleaf

I was wondering whether or not it would be possible to POST an object using ThymeLeaf and SpringBoot?

I have looked online but it doesn't seem to be very well documented.

I know the below code doesn't work but it shows the general gist of what I want to achieve.

Please assume that there is an object passed into the view called "part" of type Part.

The Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basket")
public class BasketController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ModelAndView addToBasket(@ModelAttribute("part") Part part) {

 ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("basket/viewBasket");
 return mv;

}
}
```

And the view:

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/basket/add}" th:object="${part}" modelAttribute="part">
                <input th:object="${part}"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" th:value="#{basket.add}"/>
            </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add `Controller` level mapping also you that we can help.

Comment: @MehrajMalik Done. Thanks!

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546100/can-i-make-http-post-request-from-thymeleaf-table-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: @MehrajMalik This is exactly what I needed to do in the end. Just post the part's ID and use it to reference an object. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created some hidden fields and posted the relevant information.

The object was then re-created server side.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You've got some issues with your posted example.  We can simplify/modernize it to:

```
@Controller
public class BasketController {

    @GetMapping("/partPage") //or whatever page you're requesting
    public String getPartPage(Model model) {    
        model.addAttribute("part", new Part()); //make sure it's added to the model
        return "partPage";
    }

    //don't include blank lines after your annotations
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addToBasket(@ModelAttribute("part") Part part) {
        //do your validation or whatever    
        return "basket/viewBasket";
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<!-- just use th:object, don't need a model attribute -->
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${part}">
    <!-- remove the line about the input th:object here. doesn't make sense -->
    <!-- alternate way to show the button.  Good to include a default value for the button so you can see what the page looks like by just opening it in a browser without a server -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" th:text="#{basket.add}">Add</button>
</form>
```